# Creating Applications on Openshift with REST API

Tags: api, rest, openshift

I am trying to create an application on OpenShift using the REST API (v1.2).

When I, create a single application at a time, the thing works correctly, however, when I execute more than one create calls at the same time(in parallel) I get an error.

It is a 500 status code. And the data that comes back to me is -

```
error: "{"messages":[{
          "exit_code":1,
          "field":null,
          "severity":"error",
          "text":"Unable to create gear on node"
         }],
         "version":"1.2",
         "supported_api_versions":[1.0,1.1,1.2],
         "status":"internal_server_error",
         "data":null,
         "type":null
        }"
```

I have looked through the API documentation, I could not find what was going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation with OpenShift today. And it is not recommended to do parallel operations (like scale-up scale-down etc) on a given application or creating/deleting multiple applications at the same time.